# How to restart a windows program based on repeated errors in it's log file

Tags: windows, reboot, error-logging

how would one approach to automatically restart a windows software on repeated error messages that it writes to a log file in it's directory?

I looked at numerous software products like wintail, beartail etc. but they all can only "follow" the log file but not act on error messages.

What I'd like to achieve is:
C:\examplesoftware\log.txt

> 2019-11-08 21:20:43 ERROR Session Timeout to server
>   2019-11-08 21:20:43 ERROR Session Timeout to server
>   2019-11-08 21:20:43 ERROR Session Timeout to server

On the third appearance of "Session Timeout to server" I'd like to exit the software and make it start again.

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `.bat` file will loop until stopped, extracting every second all
lines containing the string "ERROR", count these lines (`find /c /v ""`),
compare the count with "3", and if equal do an action:

```
:loop
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr "ERROR" "C:\examplesoftware\log.txt" ^| find /c /v ""`) DO set NUMBER=%%F

if "%NUMBER%"=="3" goto found    
timeout /t 1 > NUL
goto loop
:found
echo Do it here
goto loop
```

If the program may write more than three error lines in one second,
you may add more IF commands for higher numbers, within reason.